# How to use null bytes in gperf?

Tags: hash, gnu, perfect-hash, gperf

The [gperf info pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/html_node/Binary-Strings.html) claims that if you specify `-l` then

> The keywords in the input file may contain NUL bytes, written in
>   string syntax as \000 or \x00, and the code generated by gperf will
>   treat NUL like any other byte

However when I run this input file through `gperf -L C++ -l`:

```
foo
\000bar\000
\x00baz\x00
bat
```

I get:

```
  <snip>
  static const char * wordlist[] =
    {
      "", "", "",
      "foo",
      "", "", "", "",
      "bat",
      "", "",
      "\\x00baz\\x00",
      "", "", "", "",
      "\\000bar\\000"
    };
  <snip>
```

Which looks like it's treating the `\000` and `\x00` as literal values rather than null bytes.

How can I use correctly specify null bytes in my gperf strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find a more precise documentation of the input syntax in [section "Format for Keyword Entries"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/html_node/Keywords.html):

> It can be given in two ways: as a simple name, i.e., without surrounding
>   string quotation marks, or as a string enclosed in double-quotes, in C syntax,
>   possibly with backslash escapes like \" or \234 or \xa8.

And in gperf's test suite, you find [an example](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gperf.git;a=blob_plain;f=tests/lang-ucs2.gperf;hb=HEAD):

```
"\x00\x45\x00\x6E\x00\x67\x00\x6C\x00\x69\x00\x73\x00\x68",    "English",    "en_GB.UTF-8"
```